# A problem with eigenvectors of a Hermitian(?) Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

I have this matrix:

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
   1      & -1  & 0 \\
    -1      & 2  & -1  \\
    0       & -1 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}$$

Eigenvalues are $\lambda_i=0,1,3$

Corresponding eigenvectors:

$v_{\lambda=0}$\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\1\\1 \end{bmatrix}

$v_{\lambda=1}$\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\0\\-1 \end{bmatrix}
$v_{\lambda=3}$\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\-2\\1 \end{bmatrix}

Now, $A=XDX^{-1}$ as it should (where D is the eigenvalues matrix). But my notes say the following:[image]

And in a sense $A$ is hermitian (because it is symmetric), so we should have that $$A=XDX^T$$ but $XDX^T=\begin{bmatrix}
   4      & -6  & 2 \\
    -6      & 12  & -6  \\
    1      & -2 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}\neq A$

What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT: After using Jose's hint everything works:

[image]

Comment: There must be some problem with your computation; if $D$ is diagonal, then $XDX^\top$ should definitely be (at least) symmetric.

Comment: You need to make sure you normalize $X$ in the right way. As Jose wrote.

Comment: Please replace the screenshot by a text quotation of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your matrix $X$ is *not* orthogonal: the columns do not have norm $1$. Divide each column by its norm, and all will be fine then. Not being orthogonal means that $X^{-1}\neq X^T$.

Comment: I think you mean $X$ is not orthogonal. $A$ is equal to its conjugate transpose, hence it is Hermitian.

Comment: I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Comment: Done. And I've added another sentence too.

Comment: Thanks, it works now !